# Store cache according to the URL

Tags: html, url, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I am creating a Java web application using the Vaadin framework, nevertheless the question concerns any type of web application. The application consists of several modules and I have implemented it in that way, that any module appears according to the URL. In particular a parameter in the URL determines which module must appear. The problem is the influence of the cache on the functionality of the application, since every it runs with an URL having been used previously, it brings the application stored in cache and therefore the last module appeared, not the module indicated by the URL.

I want to know if an attainable approach would be to store the application separate in the cache according to the URL. For instance if there are 10 modules, hence 10 URLs, a `cache.manifest` file should be used for each one:

```
cache.manifest_module1
cache.manifest_module2
...
cache.manifest_module10
```

Could that be implemented and how? How could then I lead each time the application, which runs under a specific URL, to be stored in the correct (specific) `cache.manifest` file?

**Update:** I have read also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843531/html5-cache-is-it-possible-to-have-several-distinct-caches-for-a-single-url), which points out that it is possible to link each url to a cache-manifest file, but it does not explain how. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question? Is the browser cache the problem? How many webapps are there (which URls) ... What is the relationship to "java-ee"?

Comment: Although I am not deeply acquainted with cache cases, I think the problem is the app-cache, not the browser cache. It has to do with "splitting" the cache-manifest according the url, which refers to app-cache.

Comment: @Beryllium: question concerns HTML5 appcache. I fixed the tagging.